# How to get dual variables in Pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo

I want to get the dual variables of my linear optimization problem in **[pyomo](/questions/tagged/pyomo)**. I first tried the same written as documented [**here**](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoOnlineDocs.html#_accessing_duals).

```
model.dual = Suffix(direction=Suffix.IMPORT)
print( "Duals" )
from pyomo.core import Constraint
for c in model.component_objects( Constraint, active = True ):
    print( "Constraint", c )
    cobject = getattr( model, str( c ) )
    for index in cobject:
        print( "  ", index, model.dual[cobject[index]] )
```

It is exactly the same as in the documentation, but still I get following error-message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\kernel\component_map.py", line 97, in __getitem__
    return self._dict[id(obj)][1]
KeyError: 1401849508200

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Usuario/PycharmProjects/untitled/Model.py", line 214, in <module>
    model.dual[model.cPowermatched[(0,0)]]
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\kernel\component_map.py", line 100, in __getitem__
    % (id(obj), str(obj)))
KeyError: "Component with id '1401849508200': cPowermatched[0,0]"
Exception ignored in: <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x00000146647164E0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 154, in __del__
Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.
```

It seems to get stuck when I try to access the dual value by

```
model.dual[cobject[index]]
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you declare a `dual` Suffix before solving your model?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have written this in the beginning

Comment: I fixed it by using model.dual.get([cobject[index])

Comment: I had the same issue and, at least in my case, it appears it was due to the presence of binary variables. After obtaining an optimizer, I [fixed the binary variables](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working_models.html#fixing-variables-and-re-solving) and solved the problem again. Then I was able to retrieve the dual variables just like you are trying to.

Answer (score 0):

Something that may help your troubleshooting is simply doing `model.dual.display()`, if your model is not too large to display all the duals.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to do so, but the only output I get out of it is:

dual : Direction=Suffix.IMPORT, Datatype=Suffix.FLOAT
    Key : Value
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.

So nothing that would help me I think. Also I have already gotten an output by using model.dual.get([cobject[index]), but somehow all the variables are containing a value of none. Which is just very strange since I can see in the results that some are inequality contraints are active.

Comment: I'm not surprised that you're retrieving values of `None`, since I believe `get()` returns `None` if no matching element was found. That's also why your `display()` outputted nothing. Your dual Suffix is not being populated by the solver. Did you declare `model.dual = Suffix(direction=Suffix.IMPORT)` before calling `SolverFactory('your_solver').solve(model)`?

Comment: Yes I declared this line right in front of SolverFactory(). Does it maybe have to do with the fact that I am using Pyomo 5.5.0 and the documentation is for an earlier release? Did they maybe change the syntax or something like that?

Comment: 5.5.0 shouldn't have introduced that kind of change. Going down the process of elimination, do you know that your solver terminated correctly? `SolverFactory('your_solver').solve(model, tee=True)`

Comment: I have the feeling I am hitting the same issue as you. Did you manage to solve it? For me it seems the dual is empty because I have binary variables, but there has to be a way of getting the reduced-cost value. Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65523319/pyomo-accesing-retrieving-dual-variables-shadow-price-with-binary-variables